Why does plot in SageMath generate a 'Substitution using function-call syntax and unnamed arguments has been removed. ' error?
The following code works fine:
h(x) = hypergeometric((-1/2, 1/3), (4/3,), -x^3)
print(N(h(2)))
plot(h, (0, 4))

However, the following code generates errors when it gets to the plot:
h(x) = hypergeometric((-1/2, 1/3), (4/3,), -x^3) + 3
print(N(h(2)))
plot(h, (0, 4))

These are the errors generated:
verbose 0 (3899: plot.py, generate_plot_points) WARNING: When plotting, failed to evaluate function at 200 points.

verbose 0 (3899: plot.py, generate_plot_points) Last error message: 'Substitution using function-call syntax and unnamed arguments has been removed. You can use named arguments instead, like EXPR(x=..., y=...)'

Why should adding a 3 to a symbolically defined function cause such a problem?
I expected the second plot to be simply a vertical shift of the first plot.
Note that both definitions of h can be evaluated with h(2) and N(h(2)).
So, it appears that there is a problem with function evaluation somewhere inside the plot function.
